# Create button with Jquery that change the url attribute based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to add a button for the WhatsApp link, that changes the WhatsApp pre-text with user checkbox.

This what I've got so far:

```js
$('.cb').click(function() {
      if($(this).is(":checked")){

      var cbVal = $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').text();

      var href = $('a').attr('href');
      href += cbVal + (',');
      $('a').attr('href', href)

      }
  });
```

```css
.fieldset {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <legend>Select Menu Item</legend>
  <input id="checkbox12" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox12">Burger</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox22" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox22">Juice</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox32" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox32">Ice Cream</label><br/>
</fieldset>

<button>
<a href="https://wa.me/123456?text=I%20want%20to%20order:%20">Order Now</a>
</button>
```

So when I checked the checkbox, the URL attribute for the button is added. The problem is, when I uncheck the checkbox, the URL attribute is not removed.

Please help what have I missed?

*also it is very nice when someone can re-write the JS into pure vanilla javascript without jquery :)

Thank you

Comment: is because you code that update link is inside if... you need update the link on every click change, the if statment will only change the url variable

Comment: just add an `else` block where you remove the attribute: `if($(this).is(":checked")) { ... } else { $('a').removeAttr('href'); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrited some of the code to open the link only when users click on the link via `onlick` attribute.

I also recommend that your put the values on checkbox value attribute, because you can control what go in URL and what is visible to user in more simple way.

```js
function openLink() {
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".cb:checked");
    const link = "https://wa.me/123456?orders=" + Array.from(inputs).map(x => x.value).join();
    console.log(link);
    // now you can open the window via:
    // window.open(link, "_blank");
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <legend>Select Menu Item</legend>
  <input id="checkbox12" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="burguer">
  <label for="checkbox12">Burger</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox22" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="juice">
  <label for="checkbox22">Juice</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox32" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="ice-cream">
  <label for="checkbox32">Ice Cream</label><br/>
</fieldset>

<button>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink()">Order Now</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is mantain the update link functionality but always recreate the URL when users click on checkbox

```js
function updateLink() {
  const selectedInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".cb:checked");
  const url = "https://wa.me/123456?orders=" + Array.from(selectedInputs).map(x => x.value).join();
  document.getElementById("wp-link").setAttribute("href", url);
  console.log(url);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
  document.body.querySelectorAll(".cb").forEach(x => {
    x.addEventListener("click", updateLink, true)
  });
});
```

```html
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <legend>Select Menu Item</legend>
  <input id="checkbox12" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="burguer">
  <label for="checkbox12">Burger</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox22" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="juice">
  <label for="checkbox22">Juice</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox32" class="cb" type="checkbox" value="ice-cream">
  <label for="checkbox32">Ice Cream</label><br/>
</fieldset>

<button>
<a id="wp-link" href="javascript:void(0)" >Order Now</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop on checked input and generate the link everytime user click on checkbox.

```js
$('.cb').click(function() {
  var href = "https://wa.me/123456?text=I%20want%20to%20order:%20";
  
  $('.cb').each(function(index, value) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var cbVal = $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').text();
      href += cbVal + (',');
    }
  });
  
  $('a.whatsappLink').attr('href', href);
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(href);
});
```

```css
.fieldset {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <legend>Select Menu Item</legend>
  <input id="checkbox12" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox12">Burger</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox22" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox22">Juice</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox32" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox32">Ice Cream</label><br/>
</fieldset>

<button>
<a href="https://wa.me/123456?text=I%20want%20to%20order:%20" class="whatsappLink">Order Now</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function removeItem(arr, target) {
  const aux = arr.slice()
  
  aux.some((item, idx) => {   
    if (item === target) {
      const a = arr.splice(idx, 1)
      return true
    }
    return false
  })
  
  return arr
}

$('.cb').click(function() {
      var href = $('a').attr('href');
      var url = href.split(',')
      
      var cbVal = $('label[for=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').text();
      
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
        url.push(cbVal);
      } else {
        url = removeItem(url, cbVal)
      }
      
      $('a').attr('href', url.join())
      $('#result').text($('a').attr('href'))
  });
  
  $('#result').text($('a').attr('href'))
```

```css
.fieldset {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <legend>Select Menu Item</legend>
  <input id="checkbox12" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox12">Burger</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox22" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox22">Juice</label><br/>
  <input id="checkbox32" class="cb" type="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox32">Ice Cream</label><br/>
</fieldset>

<button>
<a href="https://wa.me/123456?text=I%20want%20to%20order:%20">Order Now</a>
</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```